# Typing long commands on command prompt using shortcut

Tags: command-prompt

While working on command prompt I frequently use commands ,which require lot of time to manually type. I know there must be some shortcuts by which I can make this command in a shortcut and achieve desired result.
I am aware that we can use previously executed command using arrow , but that doesn't suits my requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your requirement?  `Tab` is a completion key in Windows, but batch files might suit you better.

Comment: what I am looking for is a small command which I can execute from any path and this small command will actually save my efforts of typing very long command. Possible??

Comment: Yes.  A batch file can be called 1 or 2 or 3 letter names for example, and it can be written to execute very long commands and add parts in that are variable.  What goes in the batch file depends on precisely what you are typing in.

Answer (score 1):

You can use alias. Just add the following line in the end of your, .bashrc (or .zshrc)

```
alias <shortcut_command>='<your_long_command>'
```

Ex:

```
alias proj='cd /Users/rival/Desktop/java/stweik'
```

Answer (score 0):

You may put your commands in a file inside /usr/local/bin/ and give it permission for being executable.

Then you can directly type the file name to call the script.